# Can useOptimistic Hook be used with boolean values?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have this switch component where its checked value is updated if the user is an admin, and after the update, it refetches the data.

When I click the switch, it still takes some time to load and then only updates, it's not happening as expected to update first and then revalidate.

```js
import React, { useOptimistic } from 'react';
import { Switch } from '@/components/ui/switch';
import { FirebaseUser } from '@/typings/user';
import { QueryObserverResult, RefetchOptions } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { updateUserAdminAccess } from '@/services/admin';
import { toast } from 'sonner';
import { AxiosError } from 'axios';

const ControlUserAdminSwitch: React.FC<ControlUserAdminSwitchProps> = ({
    role,
    uid,
    refetch,
}) => {
    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useOptimistic(role === 'ADMIN');

    const handleUpdateUserAccess = async (checked: boolean) => {
        try {
            await updateUserAdminAccess(uid, role);
            toast.success(
                `User admin access ${
                    checked ? 'granted' : 'revoked'
                } successfully.`
            );
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
                switch (error.response?.data.message) {
                    case 'app/user-not-found': {
                        toast.error('User not found');
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'app/user-admin-access-failed': {
                        toast.error('User admin access update failed');
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        toast.error(
                            'Unable to update user admin access. Please try again later.'
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            refetch();
        }
    };

    return (
        <Switch
            checked={isAdmin}
            onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
                setIsAdmin(checked);
                handleUpdateUserAccess(checked);
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

Can optimistic updates work with boolean values or does it have to be an array type update?

Comment: Where does the `useOptimistic` hook come from？

Comment: `import { useOptimistic } from 'react';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the asynchronous operation, you are updating isAdmin using SetIsAdmin and updating it again in the last block after the asynchronous operation.

Here's a modified version of your code without using useOptimistic

```
const ControlUserAdminSwitch: React.FC<ControlUserAdminSwitchProps> = ({
role,
uid,
refetch,

}) => {
const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(role === 'ADMIN');


const handleUpdateUserAccess = async (checked: boolean) => {
    try {
        await updateUserAdminAccess(uid, role);
        toast.success(
            `User admin access ${
                checked ? 'granted' : 'revoked'
            } successfully.`
        );
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
            switch (error.response?.data.message) {
                case 'app/user-not-found': {
                    toast.error('User not found');
                    break;
                }
                case 'app/user-admin-access-failed': {
                    toast.error('User admin access update failed');
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    toast.error(
                        'Unable to update user admin access. Please try 
                         again later.'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        refetch();
    }
};

return (
    <Switch
        checked={isAdmin}
        onCheckedChange={async (checked) => {
            setIsAdmin(checked);
            await handleUpdateUserAccess(checked);
        }}
    />
);
};
```

After the asynchronous operation, the isAdmin state is updated.